# UITableView commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath with ARC causes leak?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, automatic-ref-counting

When an user deletes some table row with swipe-to-delete action,
**Instruments Tool** shows that the deleted `UITableViewCell` instance is still alive.

I used very ordinary approach that is:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
        // Do Some Processing Model things...

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }

}
```

I can't sure but I think It is bug that is related with ARC.
May I leave this problem or should I have to find any walk around?

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

TableView holds on to the cell so it can reuse them later.

Comment: Yes it is. However, the cell(deleted by swipe) is still alive after the `UITableViewController` is deallocated.

Comment: That's weird. Make sure you don't  have a strong reference cycle between tableview and the delegate.

Comment: This is reproducible with examples from Apple also. This leak is only occurs when swipe to delete case only.